# How to create a new column for each unique component in a given column of a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am relatively new to Pandas so my sincere apologies if the question was not framed properly. I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                         'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                   'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                         'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                   'C': np.random.randn(8)})



     A      B         C         
0  foo    one  0.469112 
1  bar    one -0.282863 
2  foo    two -1.509059
3  bar  three -1.135632  
4  foo    two  1.212112  
5  bar    two -0.173215 
6  foo    one  0.119209 
7  foo  three -1.044236
```

What I want to achieve is following,

```
           foo_B         foo_C      bar_B      bar_C          
0             one        0.469112     -           -
1             -            -          one        -0.282863 
2             two        -1.509059    -            -
3             -               -       three    -1.135632               
4             two         1.212112    -            -
5              -              -       two      -0.173215 
6             one         0.119209      -           -
7              three     -1.044236      -           -
```

I exactly don't know which pandas function to use to obtain such a result. Kindly help

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need this output?

Comment: yes this was just a simple example but I am working on a more complex data frame where I need this sort of sorting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it with [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) the column A with `append=True` to keep the original index, and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). Then rename the columns as wanted in your output.

```
df_f = df.set_index('A', append=True).unstack()
df_f.columns = [f'{col[1]}_{col[0]}' for col in df_f.columns]
print (df_f)
   bar_B  foo_B     bar_C     foo_C
0    NaN    one       NaN -0.230467
1    one    NaN  0.230529       NaN
2    NaN    two       NaN  1.633847
3  three    NaN -0.307068       NaN
4    NaN    two       NaN  0.130438
5    two    NaN  0.459630       NaN
6    NaN    one       NaN -0.791269
7    NaN  three       NaN  0.016670
```

Comment: Man, the messy path I was going down for this one. Haha. Very nice answer :D

Comment: @ALollz same, was going to do two pivots, concat and then cumcount with chr to map the column names. much neater. totally forgot about the append argument

Comment: Thank you :)) Makes things really simple